# Oracle SQL Developer Query - Select most recent record and count by another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a novice with SQL and sure this is much more simple I can think of. 
I am looking to get the most recent record on a table and then count the most recent record by status. Some ability return a count by status and month/year

```
would be a bonus. 
So table is the following:
ID     STATUS     TIMESTAMP
1      ACTIVE     04/19/2016
1      PENDING    04/18/2016
2      ACTIVE     04/08/2016
2      PENDING    04/01/2016
3      PENDING    04/07/2016
4      PENDING    12/01/2015
5      CANCELLED  12/30/2015
```

When I run the query I am wanting the following:

```
ACTIVE    04/2016 2
PENDING   04/2016 1 
CANCELLED 12/2015 1
```

I am able to get the most recent record by using the following:

```
Select id,
    status,
    date  from (
Select TABLE_A, 
    status, 
    date,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by date Desc) col
From TABLE_A) ps
Where ps.col = 1;
```

Thank you for your patience in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most of the way there.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select status, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, count(*)
from (Select TABLE_A, status, date,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date Desc) as seqnum
      From TABLE_A
     ) ps
Where seqnum = 1
group by select status, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') ;
```

Comment: This worked great. For my specific scenario I had to tweak it just a tad, but this helped so much. My modifications where as follows 
select status, to_char(status_date, 'YYYY-MM')as YYYYMM, count(*) 
from (Select status, date,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date Desc) as seqnum
      From TABLE_A
     ) ps
Where seqnum = 1
group by status, to_char(date, 'YYYY')
order by 2 asc, 1 asc;